# Select particular record if match is found otherwise First record in IGrouping<T>

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my LINQ query:

```
pmcPrices = (from pd in interfaceCtx.PmcPriceDatas
            where
            pd.ClientIdValue != null
            && pd.ClientIdCode == "FII"
            && (pd.MetricVal != null || pd.PMCPrice1 != null || pd.PMCPrice2 != null)
            && pd.EffectiveDate.Value == eodDate.DateTime
            group pd by pd.ClientIdValue into g
            select g).ToDictionary(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.Key),
                                   g => g.SingleOrDefault(p => p.FeedCode == "EQRMS-CB"));
```

What I want to achieve is if any of the record in group 'g' has FeedCode == 'EQRMS-CB' select that record otherwise First record in group 'g'.

Comment: I would probably do this as two queries. If the first doesn't return a value with the FeedCode (not .Any()) then run the second without the where clause that just does an order by and returns the first record. Otherwise the LINQ could get pretty complex...

Comment: Just be sure your call to `First` is deterministic, order the elements of the group. Nothing worse than running the same code and getting different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't actually matter which you get if there is no match so long as you get one, or if you are using a Linq provider with a stable `OrderBy` (linq to objects and providers that make use of it is, most are not) then:

```
g => g.OrderBy(p => p.FeedCode != "EQRMS-CB").FirstOrDefault()
```

Otherwise:

```
g => g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FeedCode == "EQRMS-CB") ?? g.FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
..
.ToDictionary(g => Convert.ToInt32(g.Key), 
         g => g.Any(p => p.FeedCode == "EQRMS-CB") 
                 ? g.First(p => p.FeedCode =="EQRMS-CB") 
                 : g.First())
```

Comment: or `g => g.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FeedCode == "EQRMS-CB") ?? g.First()`